# Using Arrays instead of Lists Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist, linked-list

This method has to remove duplicate elements from the passed-through array at 2 index points. However, I learned that we are not allowed to use Arraylist or LinkedLists, only Arrays. How can I make this work?

```html
public Animal[] removeDuplicateAnimals(Animal[] animals, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
       int constFromIndex = fromIndex;
       ArrayList<Animal> uniqueAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
       Animal[] uniqueAnimalsArray = new Animal[0];
       uniqueAnimals.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(animals, 0, fromIndex)));
       boolean existingFlag;
       while (fromIndex < toIndex) {
           existingFlag = false;
           if(uniqueAnimals.size() == 0)
               uniqueAnimals.add(animals[fromIndex]);
           else {
               int j = (constFromIndex - 1) > 0 ? (constFromIndex - 1): 0;
               for (; j < uniqueAnimals.size(); j++)
                   if(uniqueAnimals.get(j).equals(animals[fromIndex])) {
                       existingFlag = true;
                       break;
                   }
               if(!existingFlag)
                   uniqueAnimals.add(animals[fromIndex]);
           }
           fromIndex++;
       }
       uniqueAnimals.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(animals, toIndex, animals.length)));
       return uniqueAnimals.toArray(uniqueAnimalsArray);
   }
```

Comment: Use 'HashSet constructor' with 'Collection' param for which convert  Array to List as 'Arrays.asList()'..

Comment: Basic plan: Create an array whose size is `animals.length`.  Instead of `ArrayList.add` to add an element, use something like `resultArray[resultIndex++] = ` the element to add.  When you're done, the array you want to return may be shorter than `animals`, so you can use `Arrays.copyOfRange` to return the first however-many elements.  I think you can work out the details.

Answer (score 0):

This has some unhandled edge cases (OOBExceptions etc), but if I understand what you're asking something like this should work:

```
public Animal[] removeDuplicateAnimals(Animal[] animals, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    int modifiedAnimalsSize = animals.length;

    for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < toIndex; j++) {
            int k = modifiedAnimalsSize -1;
            if (animals[i].equals(animals[j])) {
                animals[j] = animals[k];
                animals[k] = null;
                modifiedAnimalsSize--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    // return a new array which is resized
    return Arrays.copyOf(animals, modifiedAnimalsSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each animal at index i in the array, search through the indices of the array from i+1 to toIndex for the same animal; if there is a duplicate, write null at that index i in the original array. This will not resize the array. It will just replace duplicates with null.

```
public Animal[] removeDuplicateAnimals(Animal[] animals, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
       for (int i = fromIndex; i++; i < toIndex) {
           for (int j = i+1; j++; j <= toIndex) {
               if (animals[i].equals(animals[j])) {
                   animals[i] == null;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       return animals;
   }
```